# sh: 1: /my_path/ompi-1.1/compiler/ompi: permission denied when I run my C program

Tags: c, sh, permission-denied

I have installed a software named "OMPi" (after `make`, it generated two executable file `ompicc` and `ompi`, and you can use `ompicc -x file` to do something, and `ompi` will be called by `ompicc`).

When I run the command `ompicc ~/Documents/example.c` in the directory "/my_path/ompi-1.1/compiler" (`ompicc` is here and `ompi` is in the sub_path "./ompi/"), an error occurred **sh: 1: /my_path/ompi-1.1/compiler/ompi: permission denied**. But when I ran the same command in any other directories, the error didn't occur.

`sudo chmod 777 -R ompi-1.1` is no use.

I think it may be because the sub_path "./ompi/" get the same name with file `ompi`. So, I created a directory named "ompi/" in home_path, and then ran the above command. To my surprise, the error didn't occur. It seems that the error only occur when I run the command in the directory: `/my_path/ompi-1.1/compiler/`

[information in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtzfY.png)

Comment: Whatever your problem is, ***`chmod 777` is wrong* and a serious security issue.** Unfortunately, the `-R` option makes this very hard to revert; perhaps you can simply wipe that directory and start over?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it (I have briefly checked ompi's source code), the **ompi** program is expected by **ompicc** to be in the same directory. It worked fine after you had created /ompi/ in home directory, because you still had executable of the same name in the same directory as **ompicc**. It doesn't work in the directory you specified because there's only one **ompi** there which is a directory.

Line that does the execution in ompicc.c (the constructed command is then ran by a **system()** call:

```
sprintf(cmd, "%s%s%s \"%s.pc\" __ompi__%s%s%s%s%s%s%s %s > \"%s\"%s",
        usegdb ? "gdb " : "", /* Run gdb instead of running _ompi directly */
        RealOmpiName,
        usegdb ? " -ex 'set args" : "", /* Pass the arguments */
       /* ...further arguments here... */
```

To confirm that RealOmpiName is 'ompi' i followed the program and
**RealOmpiName** is traced back to (through external symbol OmpiName)
Makefile.am:

```
-DOmpiName='"_@PACKAGE_TARNAME@"' \
```

Which then is used like this (to install the software):

```
cp -f ompi $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/_@PACKAGE_TARNAME@
cp -f ompicc $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/@PACKAGE_TARNAME@cc
```

I think the installer wouldn't put the two programs together if it didn't require the two to be in the same directory in the first place.

**Solution:** ompi and ompicc have to be in the same folder/directory.